# Latex: How to encapsulate text in an amsmath block

Tags: text, alignment, latex, equation, amsmath

My first stackoverflow question. I take the easy way out and directly ask the following. How is it possible to produce an output in LaTeX, like the one pictured below?

[image]

More holistic, what are the best ways to encapsulate text in an amsmath eg. equation, align, block?

Comment: Hi! Remember to mark one of the answers below as accepted, if any solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `\text{}` command to write text in amsmath blocks:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    ID_V &= \text{identifier of $V$} \\
    P_C  &= \text{password of user on $C$}
\end{align}

\begin{alignat}{2}
    &ID_V &&= \text{identifier of $V$} \\
    &P_C  &&= \text{password of user on $C$}
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `tabular` environment. This code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
$ID_V$ & = identifier of $V$\\
$P_C$ & = password of user on $C$\\
$AD_C$ & = network address of $C$\\
$K_V$ & = secret encryption key shared by $AS$ and $V$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

produces:

[image: screenshot of output]

Then you can indent or align the tabular as you prefer.

Only a hint about the second part of your question. Keep in mind which environments, like `tabular`, have text as default content (hence math must be included in `$...$`) and which ones, like `array`, `align`, `equation`, etc., have math as default (so that text must be included in a box or in `\text{...}`).